# Xubuntu service send data over serial port

Tags: xubuntu, modem, serial-port

when i open a serial terminal (i.e. minicom) some data are send automatically from my pc to the device, these data are:

```
AT+GMI ~x�~ ~x�~
```

I know that by default there is a modem client doing this kind of pairing/handshaking/syncing, i have already removed it from another pc, but i forgot the name, can someone say me which one is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was generated by the modemanager package, i have not find a way to disable it, if you want to remove the manager simply do:

```
sudo apt-get purge modemmanager
```